# Aligning words vertically and horizontally in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a script which checks for the CVE details from redhat database and gets the output to a text file.

Here is the output of the script.

```
CVE-2017-3289
Critical Impact
2017-01-17
--
CVE-2017-5335
Moderate Impact
2017-01-10
--
CVE-2017-5336
Moderate Impact
2017-01-10
--
CVE-2017-5337
Moderate Impact
2017-01-10
--
CVE-2017-5581
Low Impact
2017-01-13
--
CVE-2017-6074
Important Impact
2017-02-22
```

Now, I need to format the text and make them look as follows:

```
CVE-2017-3289 | Critical Impact | 2017-01-17
CVE-2017-5335 | Moderate Impact | 2017-01-10
CVE-2017-6074 | Important Impact | 2017-02-22
```

Comment: Please add the Bash script source code you are using now.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. If you have attempted to write something and have some difficulties, then show what you have done and ask a specific question.
Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips. If you just want free work done then StackOverflow isn't the place for such requests.
Learn to write your code yourself or pay someone to write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed '/CVE/{N;N; s/\n/ | /g; n; /--/d}' yourfile
```

The output:

```
CVE-2017-3289 | Critical Impact | 2017-01-17
CVE-2017-5335 | Moderate Impact | 2017-01-10
CVE-2017-5336 | Moderate Impact | 2017-01-10
CVE-2017-5337 | Moderate Impact | 2017-01-10
CVE-2017-5581 | Low Impact | 2017-01-13
CVE-2017-6074 | Important Impact | 2017-02-22
```